# How do I change the text of multiple bookmarks by stepping through an array?

Tags: vba, syntax, ms-word

```
Sub initialize()

    For boxNum = 1 To 10
        vaultValuesForm.Controls("h" & boxNum).Value = ""
        vaultValuesForm.Controls("d" & boxNum).Value = ""
    Next boxNum
    
    vaultValuesForm.Show
        
End Sub
Sub button_Populate_Click()

    Dim array_h(9) As String, array_d(9) As String
    
        For boxNum = 0 To 9
            array_h(boxNum) = vaultValuesForm.Controls("h" & (boxNum + 1)).Value
            array_d(boxNum) = vaultValuesForm.Controls("d" & (boxNum + 1)).Value
        Next boxNum
        
        Call populateTable(array_h(), array_d())
        
End Sub
Sub populateTable(array_0() As String, array_1() As String)

        For x = 1 To 4
            ThisDocument.Bookmarks("bd" & x).Range.Text = array_0(0)
        Next x
        
End Sub
```

I have tested the functionality of this code at various points, and it works flawlessly right up until this line:

```
ThisDocument.Bookmarks("bd" & x).Range.Text = array_0(0)
```

Specifically, until it reaches `= array_0(0)`. In its current state, reaching this point in the Sub results in "Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist." Same deal when I originally tried using `= array_0(x)` (which is ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish). However, if replaced with something direct such as `= "AA"`, it works. How do I phrase this bit properly to set the bookmark values to those within the array?

**Note**: In case you're wondering, the arrays are being referenced and passed properly; I tested this by changing the loop to comments and using MsgBox() with various array elements.

Comment: When code stops on error, moving the cursor over `array_0(0)`, what does it show? Check also what value `x` has. I am thinking that maybe the problem should be in  `Bookmarks("bd" & x)`...

Comment: @FaneDuru 'array_0(x) = "1" ', which is correct for what I entered into the TextBox.

Comment: So, the bookmark you try to set a value does not exist (anymore)...

Comment: @slightlysnarky You're right! Which makes sense, because testing it by directly setting the bookmark with text always worked, so when I adjusted the syntax and tried again, the bookmark was gone. Thanks you guys!

Comment: Which is why you should always use code like `If ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("bd" & x)` before you attempt to do anything with a bookmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from comments. The issue I wasn't aware of was that the bookmarks were being deleted after running the module, so it wouldn't work again unless the bookmarks were created again.

*Are you sure the bookmarks bd1...bd4 are still there in the document? Because a bookmark's range.text deletes the bookmark, so if you want to be able to repeat the bookmark text assignments you have to recreate the bookmarks after assigning the texts. FWIW I ran your code and it was fine when bd1..bd2 etc. existed but threw 5941 the next time. (This is quite a common problem!) – slightly snarky Sep 3 at 8:37*

So, for the official answer to my question, the way I had done it initially is how; it just couldn't be repeated.